# Generate multiple themes using webpack and less

Tags: css, less, webpack

I am using webpack as the build tool, less as the css pre-processor in my application.

I have a less file named `variable.less` which contains the general values like color,size for the whole site, then different components require different less which use the variables defined in the `variable.less`

Now we need to create multiple themes for the site, I am not sure how to get start, any suggestions?

Comment: How are you planning to load those themes?

Comment: Add class for the `html` element when the theme changed. For example `<html class="theme-a"... `  `<html class="theme-b"... `

Comment: Ok, you can definitely generate the theme bundles with webpack (separate entries, `ExtractTextPlugin`). It's loading the themes that gets interesting. You'll need to use some dynamic solution for that. Essentially you just need to set style to point at the right file through JavaScript, though. Would this be enough for an answer?

Comment: All the styles are bundled in the js on my application at the moment, there are only on entry point(js), so can you give more details?

Comment: I wrote about the basic idea [here](http://survivejs.com/webpack/building-with-webpack/separating-css/). You'll end up with a separate `entry` for your themes like that. Webpack will write css and empty js (useless file) for each through `ExtractTextPlugin`. You can then refer to these files through JavaScript to achieve dynamic loading you want.

Comment: hguser, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Similar problem and my solution is webpack plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46624753/how-to-configure-webpack-to-generate-separate-css-themes/51128587#51128587