# How to configure webpack to generate separate css themes

Tags: webpack, sass, themes

I am developing a react app, that is now extended by several themes.

These themes are defined in `.scss` files in my themes folder:

```
- themes
- - theme-base.scss
- - theme.dark.scss
- - theme.light.scss
```

they contain basic color schemes with some variables, eg:

```
[theme-dark.scss]
$color-primary: #100534;
$color-primary-accent: #231454;
```

All components just use these color variables to theme them.

Now I want webpack to compile and concat my scss code to separate static css files for each theme.

I got this to work by using extractWebpackTextPlugin and some file loaders like this:

```
module.exports = env => {
  const config = require('./webpack.common')(env);
  const project = env.project;

  const postcss = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: postcssConfig(settings.browsers),
  };

  config.watch = true;
  config.devtool = 'eval';

  const themes = ['theme-base'];

  themes.forEach(themeKey => {
    const themeInstance = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/' + themeKey + '.css');
    const themePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../react/app/css/_' + themeKey + '.scss');

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.s?css$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: themeInstance.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              localIdentName: '[hash:base64:5]',
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
            }
          },
          postcss,
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              data: `@import "${themePath}";`,
            }
          }
        ]
      }),
    });

    config.plugins.push(themeInstance);
  });
}
```

**But:**
I can not add more than one theme to my array `themes`! As soon as it contains more than one item, the css and sass loaders throw errors while reading the scss files.

`Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"`

How would I setup webpack to compile one static css file for each theme?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. Did you find a solution for it?

Comment: I've answered a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021490/how-to-configure-webpack-to-generate-multiple-css-theme-files/50041851#50041851

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the similar problem currently, I try to figure it out without any invasive of codes. Then I write a webpack plugin [themes-switch](https://github.com/terence55/themes-switch) to do that. It will extact themes depends on the theme directory. Maybe it can help you.

Sample config:

```
new ThemesGeneratorPlugin({
      srcDir: 'src',
      themesDir: 'src/assets/themes',
      outputDir: 'static/css',
      defaultStyleName: 'default.less',
      themesLoader: {
        test: /\.(less|css)$/,
        loaders: [
          { loader: require.resolve('css-loader') },
          { loader: require.resolve('less-loader') }
        ]
      }
    })
```

Now I just use variables to define different colors and dimensions, then webpack would generate themes for me, and the style formats can be less, postcss and sass. Then I can make a realtime-switch in my app. The plugin will clear unused files automatically.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with hot reload. I opened an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and realized that the error occurs because you can't have multiple Webpack rules with the same `test: /\.s?css$/` condition. Anything after the first will error out.

To solve this instead create 1 rule for all of the SCSS, and the push the additional `ExtractTextPlugin` instances to the rules' `oneOf` array....

/SASS folder

```
-- app.scss
-- custom/
---- /blue/theme.scss
---- /red/theme.scss
---- /default/theme.scss
---- ...
```

The `./src/sass/app.scss?theme` entry is the default/first theme.

```
var themeDefault = "default";
module.exports = {
  entry: ['./src/app.js','./src/sass/app.scss?theme'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        oneOf: [ // use oneOf since we'll need diff rules/handlers for each .scss
          {
            resourceQuery: /theme/, 
            use: extractSass.extract({
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: "css-loader"
                  },
                  {
                    loader: "sass-loader",
                    options: {
                      allChunks: true,
                      sourceMap: true,
                      includePaths: [
                        './src/sass/custom/'+themeDefault
                      ]
                    }
                }]
            })
          }
        ],
      },

      ...
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    extractSass
  ],
  ...
}
```

Iterate each theme in the /custom folder.

```
  // iterate themes to add an entry point, rule and plugin instance for each
  fs.readdirSync('./src/sass/custom').filter(f => fs.statSync("./src/sass/custom/"+f).isDirectory()).forEach(themeKey => {
    const themeInstance = new ExtractTextPlugin('css/' + themeKey + '.css');

    module.exports.entry.push('./src/sass/app.scss?'+themeKey);

    // the SCSS rule is at index 1 in the rules array
    module.exports.module.rules[1].oneOf.push( 
    {
      resourceQuery: new RegExp(themeKey),  
      use: themeInstance.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader"
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                allChunks: true,
                includePaths: [
                  './src/sass/custom/'+themeKey
                ]
              }
          }]
      })
    });

    module.exports.plugins.push(themeInstance);

  });
```

And then in the `app.scss`, the appropriate theme folder is loaded from the `includePaths` specified in Webpack sass-loader...

```
// load theme.scss from included path
@import "theme";
...
```

Therefore, each time the `forEach` above hits the next `themeKey` the `@import "theme"` in app.scss point to a different sub folder (blue,red,etc) resulting in different CSS files for each "theme".

Comment: Do you have a working example of this on Github or something?